# AWS ECS Cluster can't be created using a custom AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ami

I am trying to autoscale my jenkins nodes and I want my jenkins nodes to be in ECS cluster as EC2 ubuntu 20.04 machines. I created an custom ubuntu 20.04 AMI with docker, ecs-agent and other software I require and when I was in create cluster wizard there I can only see Amazon Linux AMI, I can't see my custom AMI to spin up the AWS ECS EC2 cluster. What I am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating an EC2 instance using your AMI and importing it to your cluster as an External Instance? Hope this will help troubleshoot your issue.

[More Info Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-anywhere.html)

Comment: yes, that will work but it wont autoscale right? Like just that running EC2 instance will now be part of my cluster. What I want is that my cluster to be autoscaled by using that AMI

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to autoscale like that. I was just mentioning a quick hack to test if instances created from your existing AMI works with an ECS Cluster. If you need to build a ECS optimised AMI, you can use the following guide to create one.
[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/creating-custom-amazon-machine-images-with-the-ecs-optimized-ami-build-recipes/)

Another alternative is to create a launch template using your AMI and create an auto scaling group. Then, attach thet ASG to your cluster.

Comment: So is this the only way? to achieve what I'm looking for?